# "Button" shrinking after applying JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am trying to build a timer. I am in the process of coding the play and reset button. It seems to work well, except that the "button" for the play or reset button would shrink after I clicked it once, and a refresh is needed to make it the original size again. I have tried to see if there is something wrong with my code, and I am sure there is one, but I just can't find it. Here is what it is supposed to look like.

[image: This is what it's supposed to look like]

But after I clicked it, I got this.

[image]

Any idea as to why this would happen? All responses or answers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Here is the code...

```js
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector(".song");
  const play = document.querySelector(".play");

  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  const checkPlaying = (song) => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      play.textContent = `Pause`;
    } else {
      song.pause();
      play.innerHTML = `Play`;
    }
  };
}

app();
```

```css
.player-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.play {
  background: #989c99;
  box-shadow: #656a66 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.reset {
  background: #989c99;
  box-shadow: #656a66 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-container">
  <audio class="song">
    <source src="../sounds/bg-sound.mp3" />
  </audio>
  <div class="play">
    <h3>Play</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="reset">
    <h3>Reset</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because by default there is an `h3` tag inside the "button" with the text `Play` but after clicking only the text `Pause` is there, right inside the "button".

Using `h3` tag inside those buttons is incorrect anyway, so feel free to remove them. `h3` tag has semantic meaning and is for headings, not for styling. If you want to make the text bigger, use CSS, not tags.

Also, instead of using a simple `div` for your button, use the `button` element, as it's what it's there for.

```js
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector(".song");
  const play = document.querySelector(".play");

  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  const checkPlaying = (song) => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      play.textContent = `Pause`;
    } else {
      song.pause();
      play.innerHTML = `Play`;
    }
  };
}

app();
```

```css
.player-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background: #989c99;
  box-shadow: #656a66 0 6px 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-container">
  <audio class="song">
              <source src="../sounds/bg-sound.mp3" />
  </audio>
  <button class="play">
    Play
  </button>
  <button class="reset">
    Reset
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. Do you know any way for me to toggle the "btn-active" class on the reset button when clicked then after a certain period of time remove that class automatically?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Sure, you can add a class then use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method to delay the removal of the same class. Check it out on CodePen: https://codepen.io/zsoltime/pen/GRmxxgv

Answer (score 1):

While I recommend you switch to using buttons instead of `div`s with `h3` elements inside them (other answer recommended over this one basically), you can get your method to work by keeping the HTML within the `div` consistent:

```js
const app = () => {
  const song = document.querySelector(".song");
  const play = document.querySelector(".play");

  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  const checkPlaying = (song) => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      play.innerHTML = `<h3>Pause</h3>`;
    } else {
      song.pause();
      play.innerHTML = `<h3>Play</h3>`;
    }
  };
}

app();
```

```css
.player-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.play {
  background: #989c99;
  box-shadow: #656a66 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.reset {
  background: #989c99;
  box-shadow: #656a66 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-container">
  <audio class="song">
              <source src="../sounds/bg-sound.mp3" />
  </audio>
  <div class="play">
    <h3>Play</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="reset">
    <h3>Reset</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```